# Search with OR in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-search, file-search

I have a folder with countries flags "us.svg", "fr.svg", "de.svg" etc...

I need to remove all but there 3... So, is it possible to search with "OR", something like

```
us | fr | de
```

in order to cut select these files to a safe place and remove others?

Comment: [Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965711(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: You should be able to simply put `OR` in between your searches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close to the solution already.
Try this search expression:

us OR fr OR de

It should deliver results only if they match (or rather, contain) one of the three items. However, the search routine is always recursive so it will also dive into subfolders and deliver matches from the entire directory structure where you currently execute the search.

Comment: good point, also @davidpostill remark is very useful :)

Answer (score 1):

By far the best program to search on Windows is called [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/).

If you use that program, you could search using your exact query.

If you don't want to use another program, you could also just use OR.